# Maximization of $\ell^2$-norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sequences-and-series, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider for $r,c>0$ the set
$$X_{r,c}=\{x \in \ell^1(\mathbb{N}) \mid \|x\|_1=r,\,  \forall i \in \mathbb{N}: |x_i|<c\}.$$
Then I can show that $\inf_{x \in X_{r,c}} \|x\|_2 = 0.$
But is it possible to compute
$$s_{r,c}:=\sup_{x \in X_{r,c}} \|x\|_2 \text{ ?}$$
Does at least $\lim_{c \to 0} s_{r,c}=r$ hold?

Comment: The optimal arrangement should be $x=(c,c,\ldots, c,0,0\ldots)$, though it will be mildly tedious to write down carefully due to the various cases (relative size of $r,c$).

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\n}{\lfloor{r/c}\rfloor}$We have
\begin{equation*}
    s_{r,c}=\sqrt{\n c^2+(r-\n c)^2}.
\end{equation*}

Indeed, by continuity and interchangeability of the coordinates,
\begin{equation*}
    s_{r,c}^2=\sup_{a\in A_{r,c}} \sum_{i\ge1}a_i^2,
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    A_{r,c}:=\Big\{a\in[0,\infty)^\infty\colon
    \sum_{i\ge1}a_i=r,\ c\ge a_1\ge a_2\ge\cdots\Big\}.
\end{equation*}

For natural $i$, let
\begin{equation*}
    b_i:=b_{r,c;i}:=
    c\,1(i\le n)+(r-nc)\,1(i=n+1),  
\end{equation*}
where
$$n:=n_{r,c}:=\n.$$
Then $b\in A_{r,c}$.

Take any $a\in A_{r,c}$. Take any real $t>0$. Then for some nonnegative integer $n_t=n_{a;t}$ and all natural $i$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    a_i\ge t \text{ if }i\le n_t\quad\text{and}\quad a_i<t \text{ if }i>n_t.
\end{equation*}
So, if $n_t\le n$ (where $n=\n$, as above), then, letting $u_+:=\max(0,u)$, we have
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{i\ge1}(a_i-t)_+=\sum_{1\le i\le n_t}(a_i-t)
    \le\sum_{1\le i\le n_t}(c-t) \\
    =\sum_{1\le i\le n_t}(b_i-t)
    \le\sum_{i\ge1}(b_i-t)_+
\end{equation*}
and, if $n_t>n$, then
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{i\ge1}(a_i-t)_+=\sum_{1\le i\le n_t}(a_i-t) \\ 
    \le r-n_t t = \sum_{1\le i\le n_t}(b_i-t)
    \le\sum_{i\ge1}(b_i-t)_+. 
\end{equation*}
So, in any case,
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{i\ge1}(a_i-t)_+\le\sum_{i\ge1}(b_i-t)_+
\end{equation*}
for all real $t>0$.

Noting now that $u^2=2\int_0^\infty dt\,(u-t)_+$ for real $u\ge0$, we have
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{i\ge1}a_i^2=2\int_0^\infty dt\,\sum_{i\ge1}(a_i-t)_+ \\ 
    \le2\int_0^\infty dt\,\sum_{i\ge1}(b_i-t)_+=\sum_{i\ge1}b_i^2. 
\end{equation*}
So, $b$ is a maximizer of $\sum_{i\ge1}a_i^2$ over $a\in A_{r,c}$.

Thus,
\begin{equation*}
    s_{r,c}=\sqrt{\sum_{i\ge1}b_i^2}=\sqrt{nc^2+(r-nc)^2} \\ 
    =\sqrt{\n c^2+(r-\n c)^2}. \quad\Box
\end{equation*}

---

In particular, $s_{r,c}\sim\sqrt{rc}\to0$ as $c\downarrow0$. So, it is not true that $s_{r,c}\to r$ as $c\downarrow0$.